# creating shared library with gcc referring to static libraries ... visiblity?

Tags: android, linux, gcc, boost, shared-libraries

I'm trying to create a shared library for Android (linux) using gcc, something like this (simplified for clarity):

```
g++ -Wl,-soname,liba.so -Wl,--no-undefined -shared -o liba.so b.o libc.a libd.a
```

Where b.o uses symbols defined in libc.a and libd.a.  If I modify b.cc to not use symbols from libd.a, the link succeeds, otherwise it fails with undefined reference errors to the symbols defined in libd.a. Symbols defined in libc.a are correctly found.

libc.a is a library from the app under development, compiled using the same settings as the shared library in question.  libd.a is the boost iostreams library (others fail, too), built locally.  If I extract the object file d.o from libd.a and link directly to it the link succeeds.  Creating an archive using the same options used to create libc.a from the extracted d.o again fails as before.

arm-...-objdump --syms shows that the symbols reported as undefined are indeed present.  The dumped symbol info is identical for libd.a and the extracted d.o,  as one would expect.

Using -Wl,--whole-archive to force the inclusion of libd.a causes the link to succeed.

I don't have much experience with shared libraries on linux, but I suspect that c++ visibility is involved.  Both libc.a and libd.a (boost) are compiled without any visibility flags.  I suspect that boost (1.55) does something in the headers, but I haven't been able to track it down yet.

I can work around the problem for now by forcing the inclusion of any needed static libraries, but I don't really understand what's going on... can anyone shed some light?  Why might one static library be used by the linker to resolve undefined symbols but not another?

(It's not a problem with name mangling or different architectures, as I believe the experiments with ar described above demonstrate.)

Potentially interesting command line flags used when building libd.a and not libc.a:

- -fPIC
- -ffunction-sections
- -funwind-tables
- -fno-short-enums
- -fno-omit-frame-pointer
- -Wa,--noexecstack
- -fdata-sections

I'm continuing to experiment with boost compile/link flags but turnaround times are long since boost is .. well, boost.

Thanks!

Tyler

Comment: For a really quick check, try running "arm...-ranlib" on the problematic .a file. Then, it will be helpful if you included the exact error message you're getting, and also dump the list of symbols in libd.a and see whether the missing symbol is present in that output. See http://blog.vladimirprus.com/2009/06/linking-101.html for suggestions. It seems unlikely that visibility matters, as otherwise your experiment with extracting .o file and linking it it would fail as well.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion.  I've tried running ranlib to no effect.  The symbols are present and appear identically in libd.a and d.o as expected.  Dumping the symbols was the first thing I did; I'll edit the question and mention that fact.

Comment: Thanks for the edited question, but you still did not prove neither exact error message nor symbol name in question.